# Serve static files through a view in Django

Tags: python, django

I am writng a Django application that let's you download a file after some requirements have been met (you have to log on, for example). The file needs to be inaccessible otherwise.

Serve the file through Apache won't work: I have to check in the database for the user's permissions. Furthermore, don't have permission to change my Apache configuration.

So I want to read the file in Django, then set the appropriate headers and send it to the client.

I used the information on [this](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#telling-the-browser-to-treat-the-response-as-a-file-attachment) page in the Django manual for the headers.

I have the following code:

```
#<- check persmissons here, continue if allowed ->

#read the pdf file
location = 'file.pdf'
file = open(location, 'r')
content = file.read()
file.close

#serve the file
response = HttpResponse(content, mimetype='application/pdf')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=filename.pdf'

return response
```

However, the downloaded file seems to be corrupt: it can't be opened in Adobe Reader. 
I'm thinking that maybe this is some encoding problem, but I can't figure it out.

Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to `open()` the file in binary mode (consider [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#open)).

Just like this:

```
file = open(location, 'rb')
```

I don't know whether it is applicable to you (since you are not allowed to change your Apache's settings), but I'd suggest to use [Lighttpd + mod_secdownload](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/Docs:ModSecDownload#Python-example-usable-with-Django-or-any-other-Python-web-framework) for performance reasons. This elegant solution leverages Lighttpd's optimizations for serving static content while delegating authorization decisions to 3rd party (in your case Django).

Comment: Thanks, @Ignacio. I wasn't aware of similar solution from Apache world.